# jquery jqgrid add navigator bar (search,delete,add ecc.)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, navbar

I would add the navigator bar on my jqgrid like here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:navigator1.png

```
      jQuery("#tabImprese").jqGrid({
                        url:'retrieve/imprese',
                        mtype:"POST",
                        postData: { limit:'10'},
                        datatype: "json",
                        height: 150,
                        .....
                        ....
                    }).navGrid('#tabImprese',
                    {}, //options
                    {reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // edit options
                    {reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // add options
                    {reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // del options
                    {} // search options
                );
```

This is my code but in my page I don't see anything as you can see at
http://mongolera.dyndns.biz/projects/gestionalePreventivi/index.html
in Imprese tab.

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `navGrid('#tabImprese',...);` instead of `navGrid('#pagerImprese',...);`